# How to extend php class to a class which ovverride it's functions

Tags: php, class, inheritance, polymorphism

Alright, I have a structure like this:

```
class Creature{
  public function sayHi(){
      echo "Hi";
  }
}

class HumanType extends Creature(){

}

class Human extends HumanType{

}

class Human232 extends Human{
      public function sayHi(){
        echo "Hello, bro";
      }
 }

class Human457 extend Human{

}

$Human = new Human232($id);
echo $Human->sayHi(); //Hello, bro

$Human2 = new Human457($id);
echo $Human2->sayHi(); //Hi

//And then I have this still to be implemented
class HumanCategory576{
     public function sayHi(){
      echo "Hi from the category!";
  }
}
```

I have of course many classes like:
Human457,
Human458,
Human459,
Human600,
Human601

And also:
HumanCategory576,
HumanCategory577,
HumanCategory578,
HumanCategory579,
HumanCategory580

What I want to do is implement HumanCategory576 in a way that sayHi() would print "Hi from the category!" only if the Human class which is (I suppose) inheriting it is not ovveriding the function, like Human457.

I hope I was clear enough.

How do I do? Thanks

Comment: is `HumanCategory576` supposed to extend a class?

Comment: Just implement such a method in the `Human` class as the default behaviour. "Overriding" means a method of an **ancester** (extended) class is overridden in a derived (extending) class.

Comment: The matter is I need more default methods based on the category of the human. That could be done by making a switch based on the Human Category in the Human class. However, there must be a better approach because doing this means I would have  switches hundred of cases long in each default function.

Answer (score 0):

*I am assuming that it was your intention for `class` `HumanCategory576` to extend another class.*

You can use `is_callable()` to check if `HumanCategory576` parent has the function by:

```
is_callable('parent::sayHi'){
    parent::sayHi();
}else{
    echo "Hi from the category!";
}
```

Please take a [is_callable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php#104632) in PHP's documentation.

```
<?php

    class TestClass extends TestClassParent {

        /** @brief Object initialisation callback
            @returns void */
        public function __construct() {

            # do initialisation 

            # ...

            # if we have a parent 

            if(is_callable('parent::__construct')) {

                # then bubble up 

                parent::__construct();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This does not make much sense as a simple, direct inheriting OOP pattern since when you do not know whether or not some constructor exists you also do not know which arguments it expects. A well implemented OOP pattern does know the the class hierarchy a new class is derived from. Such a test is sometimes used e.g. in factory patterns where instances of multiple classes might be generated.